# get number of posts from category where meta_key is equal to?

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I'm trying to create a custom mysql query which count two things.

First of all it should count the number of posts in a category where the meta_key betting_status' value is not equal to "pending"

Then it should count the number of posts in a category where the meta_key betting_status' value is equal to yes.

So far i've done this but it does not output anything at all:

```
$wombo_query = "SELECT count(DISTINCT $wpdb->postmeta.post_id) FROM $wpdb->posts
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON
($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id)
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON
($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id) AND
WHERE $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'betting_status'
AND $wpdb->posts.meta_value = 'yes'
WHERE $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish'
AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category'
AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id = 106
";
```

Comment: where is postmeta coming from?  I don't see that table as one of the ones you're selecting from. Could that be the problem?

Comment: yes it could be the problem i tried to merge down two queries since i needed the postmeta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one.

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT wp_postmeta.`post_id`) 
  FROM wp_posts
       LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id)
       LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id)
       LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON (wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id) 
 WHERE wp_postmeta.meta_key       = 'betting_status'
    AND wp_postmeta.meta_value    = 'yes'
    AND wp_posts.post_status      = 'publish'
    AND wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category'
    AND wp_term_taxonomy.term_id  = 106;
```

Since my DB doesn't have the same values in it as yours does, this returns 0 rows for me, but it does execute.

Cheers!
=C=

Comment: Okay thank you i have another key named betting_odds where the meta value is something like 2.05 or 1.10. Any ideas on how i can add the average value of this meta value next to the count? or better to make a new query?